# Как получить доступ к аргументам события из другого метода?

Tags: c#, события, xamarin, xamarin.forms, touch-event

Вот само событие PaintSurface

```
public void OnPainting(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{   
        SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
        canvas.Clear(SKColors.White); 
}
```

Я хочу использовать canvas в другом методе,вызываемом при нажатии кнопки. К примеру использовать canvas.Clear(SKColors.White); в методе

```
private void ClearButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      canvas.Clear(SKColors.White); 
}
```

Я так понимаю,нужно что бы метод тоже получал SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs, но как это реализовать? Где можно почитать об этом или найти подобный пример?

Comment: Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой! Может быть кто-то нашел ответ?

Answer (score 2):

Объявить SKCanvas canvas глобально для этих методов

Comment: Я пробовал этот вариант, не работает(SigSegv)

Comment: @Zoom: Ну так вы его небось объявили, но не инициализировали?

Answer (score 0):

Вызовите метод [InvalidateSurface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.views.forms.skcanvasview.invalidatesurface?view=skiasharp-views-forms-2.80.2). Это в свою очередь вызовет событие `PaintSurface`.

```
private void ClearButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvalidateSurface();
}
```

При этом дополнительные данные можно передавать через поля:

```
private SKColor _color;

private void ClearButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _color = SKColors.Blue;
    InvalidateSurface();
}
```

И это поле использовать

```
public void OnPainting(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{   
    e.Surface.Canvas.Clear(_color); 
}
```